# Component import name vscode vue

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vuejs2

In vscode when i try to import a component through the autocomplete he add the word Vue in the final of the name.

for example:
`import MycomponentVue from "./components/MyComponent";`

How can i fix it??

Comment: Are you talking about autocompletion?

Comment: yes, when a try to import through the autocomplete he adds vue in the final of the name

Answer (score 0):

had the same proble, fixed adding '.vue' at the end, like this:

import MycomponentVue from "@/components/MyComponent.vue";